# Jquery - Add class on scroll when hitting div - IE and Firefox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am a working in my personal site, i am a graphic designer so coding is not my forte, i have been looking for an answer but i think maybe my issue is a little more specific:

the issue is simple, this is the link to my site: http://irvingtesting.byethost5.com/index.html

(yes, i have a mess of js scripts :( )

I have this jquery code in particular:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var aChildren = $("nav div li").children(); // find the a children of the list items
    var aArray = []; // create the empty aArray
    for (var i=0; i < aChildren.length; i++) {    
        var aChild = aChildren[i];
        var ahref = $(aChild).attr('href');
        aArray.push(ahref);
} // this for loop fills the aArray with attribute href values

$(window).scroll(function(){
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop(); // get the offset of the window from the top of page
        var windowHeight = $(window).height(); // get the height of the window
        var docHeight = $(document).height();

        for (var i=0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
            var theID = aArray[i];
            var divPos = $(theID).offset().top; // get the offset of the div from the top of page
            var divHeight = $(theID).height(); // get the height of the div in question
            if (windowPos >= divPos && windowPos < (divPos + divHeight)) {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").addClass("nav-active");
            } else {
                $("a[href='" + theID + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
            }
        }

        if(windowPos + windowHeight == docHeight) {
            if (!$("nav div li:last-child a").hasClass("nav-active")) {
                var navActiveCurrent = $(".nav-active").attr("href");
                $("a[href='" + navActiveCurrent + "']").removeClass("nav-active");
                $("nav div li:last-child a").addClass("nav-active");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

it works just fine on Google Chrome, but in IE and Firefox the .active class doesn't work until the scroll position is like in the middle of the Div 
in this case #xportfolio which is a section.

(i am using Skeleton for responsive)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reply the issue, I have Firefox 37.0, Firefox Dev Edition 39.0a2 (2015-04-06) and Google 44.0.2358.0 canary (64-bit) and It works similar (With Desktop and Responsive tools).

My suggest, read and learn in the MDN and Jquery.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/
https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

Comment: Hello, i grabbed the "highlight" code from this tutorial: http://callmenick.com/post/single-page-site-with-smooth-scrolling-highlighted-link-and-fixed-navigation

the demo page in the tutorial works fine in the latest Firefox, Latest Google Chrome and Internet Explorer 11, so i am not sure what am i doing wrong.

Comment: What is your version of FF?

Comment: According to Firefox, the Firefox version i'm using is: 37.0.1 - up to date - 
And the IE 11 version is: 11.0.9600.16384